# FluentValidation error doesn't show in View after moved to .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have fluentvalidation in my MVC .NET Core project and it can successfully return the validation error to the View.
[image]

These are the codes

```
namespace FluentValidation.Domain.FluentValidation
{
    public class InputDepositViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<InputDepositViewModel>
    {
        public InputDepositViewModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(reg => reg.Amount).NotNull().ScalePrecision(2,4);
        }
    }
}
```

But, after I moved the fluentvalidation from MVC .NET Core 3.1 project to .NET Standard 2.0 project, the fluentvalidation no longer works. The fluentvalidation error doesn't appear in my View.
[image]

Anyone knows why? Compatibility issue? But, I have checked that fluentvalidation official documentation and it supports .NET Standard 2.0.

This is my .NET Core 3.0 MVC, Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews(opt =>
            {
                opt.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidationFilterAttribute));
            }).AddFluentValidation(fvc =>
            fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
        }
```

and

```
namespace FluentValidationWebApp.ActionFilters
{
    public class ValidationFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(filterContext.ModelState);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you enable it in startup.cs?

Comment: @Neistow, I do configure it at `startup.cs`. I just added the code of my `ConfigureServices` method. By the way, I am using ActionFilters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have moved your validators to another assembly "FluentValidation.Domain"

If so, then you need to change the type while adding the fluent validation in Configure method in Startup.cs as well.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews(opt =>
        {
            opt.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidationFilterAttribute));
        }).AddFluentValidation(fvc =>
        fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<"Add a type from your FluentValidation.Domain assembly">());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I add the type from my FluentValidation.Domain assembly? I don't have `startup` class in my `FluentValidation.Domain` project.

Comment: Startup class is not mandatory. You can add in any public class from your FluentValidation.Domain Assembly.

Comment: also you can find more information over here: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html on how to register validators.